# OSX memory inconsistency (shared + private)

Tags: memory

In the picture below the shouldn't the (shared memory + private memory) equal the real memory? Am I reading this wrong? What else constitutes the real memory size? I assumed that shared memory was real memory and private memory was real memory.

Thanks in advance :-)

[image: memory image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104/whats-the-difference-between-real-virtual-shared-and-private-memory) (and the associated links) defines the terms and also offers some explanation which may help.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I still couldn't find whether are not real is shared + private or some variant of that.  But that did help :-) I understand it is roughly that, but I was looking for something definitive. +1 though for finding that :-)