# Are the per process memory and other statistics defined the same as the system wide stats?

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory

*There's been a lot of posts about memory in OSX.  None have really documented what the screen below speaks to.  Especially the difference between private memory, and virtual private memory.  Also does port represent just network ports, or does it include open file handles on that screen?* The link right here [What's the difference between Real, Virtual, Shared, and Private Memory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104/whats-the-difference-between-real-virtual-shared-and-private-memory) is not the same question.  *They're speaking of a different screen in OSX, which makes different measurements.  The screen I'm referring to in the image below is per process, not per system.  I would greatly appreciate if any one can provide information to what memory statistics in the image below represent, and what ports details.* 
[image: Ports]

[image: Private Memory and Virtual Private Memory]

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the per process memory statistics and mach call counters mean the same thing as the system wide statistics.

Activity Monitor helps you break down which specific processes are making up the conglomerated statistics if you use the screens shown above. You may also find the `sysdoagnose` command useful in probing how the various numbers all add up if you prefer a textual output as opposed to a combined graphical and textual one.