# Types of memory: Why do private and shared not add up to real memory?

Tags: catalina, memory, activity-monitor

Answers to [previous](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/104/383125) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284464/383125) define types of real memory used by a process roughly as follows:

- **Real memory**: the amount of physical memory allocated to a process (eg the number of pages)
- **Real shared memory**: the amount of physical memory shared between multiple processes
- **Real private memory**: the amount of physical memory not shared with other processes

I would have expected that `real = real_shared + real_private`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I've noticed that real memory can be more or less than shared + private, depending on the process.

Can someone please clarify the differences between these types of memory and why they don't add up?

---

MacOS Catalina 10.16.6

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: There's more than just shared and private memory.  There's reserved which is reserved by the OS, wired which is allocated and reserved to/by an App.  There's more, but I'm forgetting them at the moment - point is Apple has given you an infographic display of what they think is important to the user, not a *complete* view of everything that's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is given in [Mac OS X Process Memory Statistics](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-06-19-mac-os-x-process-memory-statistics.html)  by Mike Ash:

> RSIZE: The total amount of physical RAM used by this process. (This is not equal to RPRVT + RSHRD because they measure address space, but this measures actual memory.)

Note :

- RSIZE is Real memory
- RSHRD is Real shared memory
- RPRVT is Real private memory

You can find these abreviations by hovering the mouse on the [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac) column headers.