# Why is memory management in macOS more efficient than in Linux?

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory

I have been a Linux user for four years. Recently, I have been using macOS and I see it has very efficient memory management compared to Linux.

For example, here is a description of the documents/apps I have open on a Mac Mini i5 1.4 GHz 8GB RAM 500 GB HDD @ 5400 RPM:

- 40 pdfs
- Blender
- PowerPoint
- Photos
- iTunes
- 12 Safari tabs
- QuickTime video
- Terminal
- Maps
- Sublime Text
- Calendar

With these open the Mac showed 5.91 GB of RAM used.

My question is: What's different about the Mac that on Linux I can't even open half the apps with a machine with the same amount of memory and HD?

Comment: Repeat the test with only Qt-derived cross-platform apps and observe the exact opposite. Also: has your Linux memory compression enabled (zram)?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the efficiency comes from large blocks of read-only memory being shared between applications. Most graphical Mac applications use common frameworks. Where possible macOS only loads one instance of a framework into memory.

For more about macOS memory management and organisation see:

- [How does memory management work in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72033)
- [What's the difference between Real, Virtual, Shared, and Private Memory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104/)